# Group the number of clients by age in ranges ("under 30" - "30 - 39" ...) group by products they have bought using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Edited !!!!

Sorry I've been explaining myself wrong. So I tried to get an output like this which groups the number of clients by age in ranges ("under 30" - "30 - 39" ...) by products.

| range | product1 | product2 | ... | productn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| under 30 | 272(clients) | 250 |  |  |
| 30 to 39 | 380 | 310 |  |  |
| 40 to 49 | 410 | 450 |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |  |
| Total | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have 3 tables

```
| main      | | products | |clients   | 
| --------  | |---------| |---------  |
| main_id   | |prod_id  | | client_id |     
| client_id | |prod_cat | | birth_date|     
| product_id| |...      | |...        |     
| ...       |
```

Products

```
| prod_id  || prod_cat || ... |
| -------- || -------- ||---- |
| 1        || Apple    ||     |
| 2        || Tv       ||     |
|...       || ...      ||...  |
```

and here is what I've tried

```
    select p.prod_cat ProdCat, 
    count(case when age_average < 30 then 1 end) under 30,
    count(case when age_average between 30 and 39 then 1 end) 30 to 39,
    count(case when age_average between 40 and 49 then 1 end) 40 to 49,
    count(case when age_average between 50 and 59 then 1 end) 50 to 59,
    count(case when age_average > 60 then 1 end) over 60,
    round((months_between(sysdate,c.birth_date)/12)) age_average
    from main m
    inner join clients  c on m.client_id = c.client_id
    inner join products p on m.prod_id   = p.prod_id
    group by p.prod_cat
    order by age_average

I got the error 

> ORA-00904: "age_average": invalid id
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include representative sample data and expected results for that data. The output you have shown doesn't really make sense; the average age of people who bought products in a category can't be in two ranges at once, so there should only be one non-zero value in each column, surely? Counting how many people in each age range bought a product maybe makes sense, but how does average fit in? And are you looking for their age age now, or their age when they bought the product - if you store the purchase date, that is? (I'd also use `floor()` for ages, not `round()`.)

Comment: " Counting how many people in each age range bought a product maybe makes sense"  -> That is it! sorry, english is not my first language
 "And are you looking for their age by now," -> Yes :)

Comment: OK; but sample data would still be helpful, not least to show how `prod_id` and/or `prod_cat` translate to 'product1'etc. The output layout also only works if you have a fixed number of products (or categories?); it would be simpler to have one column per age range and one row per product, since there is a fixed number of ranges, and you need to know how many columns there will be. You can do it as you've shown, but only with a fixed number of products; otherwise it might be something you should handle in a reporting tool rather than SQL.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `age_average` column in any of those tables, so you'll have to calculate it first, and then re-use it in the rest of the query. Or, use it directly (the calculation, I mean) in every `CASE`.

Also, you'll have to enclose *labels* into double quotes; names you used are invalid.

```
with temp as
  (select p.prod_cat prodcat,
     round(avg(months_between(sysdate,c.birth_date)/12),1) age_average
   from main m
   inner join clients  c on m.client_id = c.client_id
   inner join products p on m.prod_id   = p.prod_id
   group by p.prod_cat 
  )
select prodcat,
  count(case when age_average < 30              then 1 end) "under 30",
  count(case when age_average between 30 and 39 then 1 end) "30 to 39",
  count(case when age_average between 40 and 49 then 1 end) "40 to 49",
  count(case when age_average between 50 and 59 then 1 end) "50 to 59",
  count(case when age_average > 60              then 1 end) "over 60",
  max(age_average) age_average
from temp 
group by rollup(prodcat);
```

Comment: Ok I see what you meant. And how about the row Total? sorry ... newbie here :)

Comment: Try `group by rollup(p.prod_cat)`

Comment: Unfortunatly I got this 
ORA-00937 not a single-group group function

Comment: Unfortunately. I modified query I previously posted so that it uses a CTE to find average age per PROD_CAT, and then reuses those data for your final result. See if it helps.

Comment: I tried but got ORA-00904: "p.prod_cat": invalid id

Comment: Then there's no PROD_CAT column in PRODUCTS table. Or, you did something wrong. See query I wrote, compare it to yours.

Comment: of course there is . (see edited question)

Comment: And the rest of my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the counts in each age range for the products, with the products in columns and the rows being the age range.

You need to list each product (or product category) separately.  The idea is:

```
select (case when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 30 * 12 then 'under 30'
             when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 40 * 12 then '30 to 39'
             when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 50 * 12 then '40 to 49'
             when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 60 * 12 then  '50 to 59'
             else 'over 60'
      end) as age_range,
     sum(case when product_cat = 'product1' then 1 else 0 end) as product1,
     sum(case when product_cat = 'product2' then 1 else 0 end) as product1
from main m join
     clients c
     on m.client_id = c.client_id join
     products p 
     on m.prod_id   = p.prod_id
group by (case when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 30 * 12 then 'under 30'
               when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 40 * 12 then '30 to 39'
               when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 50 * 12 then '40 to 49'
               when months_between(sysdate, c.birth_date) < 60 * 12 then  '50 to 59'
               else 'over 60'
        end)
order by max(c.birth_date) desc;
```

Comment: An d what if I have more than 1000 Products? I'm not going to list them all right?
     sum(case when product_cat = 'product1' then 1 else 0 end) as product1,
     sum(case when product_cat = 'product2' then 1 else 0 end) as product2
      ...
any idea how to use a loop or something similar?

Comment: @Newbie . . . You would list them up to the limit that Oracle has on the number of columns in a table or result set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
select p.prod_cat
  count(case when (months_between(sysdate,c.birth_date)/12) < 30      then 1 end) "under 30",
  count(case when (months_between(sysdate,c.birth_date)/12) 30 and 39 then 1 end) "30 to 39",
  count(case when (months_between(sysdate,c.birth_date)/12) 40 and 49 then 1 end) "40 to 49",
  count(case when (months_between(sysdate,c.birth_date)/12) 50 and 59 then 1 end) "50 to 59",
  count(case when (months_between(sysdate,c.birth_date)/12) > 60      then 1 end) "over 60"
from main m
inner join clients  c on m.client_id = c.client_id
inner join products p on m.prod_id   = p.prod_id
group by p.prod_cat
```